# YA sci-fi fantasy novel about a boy named "Knife" or "Blade", learns to drum

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read a story when I was a teen (late 80's early-mid 90's) about a boy abandoned to die by a tech-heavy city, only to be rescued by low-tech tribal people who live in the wild outside the city borders. The boy is named either "Knife" or "Blade" and he grows up with the tribe, eventually learning to play the giant bass drums during the tribe's ceremonies.

The cover and spine were torn off when I got it so I never learned the title, and I'm losing my mind trying to find it again. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, in the US a paperback without a cover might represent a book that was reported (to the publisher) as unsold and destroyed, in which case the author didn't receive any royalties for the book. Of course, it might just represent a book that lost it's cover.

Comment: It was likely reported as destroyed, as it was from a box of books left out by a small local library.